# What does "Enforce overwrite all files" do in TeamCity TFS VCS Root configuration?

Tags: teamcity

I occasionally have a problem where it appears that TeamCity checks out an old version of a file. For instance

- I fixed a failing test, but TeamCity didn't get the latest version, so it kept failing.
- I updated an install script on a new branch, but TeamCity didn't get the latest version, so it kept running the script with the old path.

The only thing that seems to fix the problem is to check "Enforce overwrite all files" in the VCS root configuration. But, the [latest version](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Team+Foundation+Server) of the docs do not mention this option. What does it do and why might that fix my problem?

---

My build configurations use

- VCS checkout mode: Automatically on server
- Clean all files before build: Yes

Comment: WTF, a comment on the downvote would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwrite all files is an option that affects TFS checkout on agent behavior. If you set it to true, TeamCity will call TFS to update workspace rewriting all files.
In general there is no need to do 'force' update for every build. But, if you suspect the build to change checked-in files locally, the option is for you.

If you are describing an issue where TeamCity does not take all files, please create an issue for it at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net. Do you see changes detected and files not updated? What is the version of Team Explorer/TFS server?

Comment: I don't know how check if changes are detected. And I can't force the problem to happen. Can I look in a historical log for when the problem did occur? I'm on VS2010/TFS2008.

Comment: There is a page covering most log files under TeamCity at http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Reporting+Issues Take a look on it. Detecting changes, I meant, see you TFS check-in on TeamCity web UI.

Comment: Oh, I see... yes, changes were detected and builds were triggered but, in these cases, the files were not updated.